# how to change index page/wrong url to something customized in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using `play framework 2.x`. I am seeing when the url is not in the ones as specified in `route`, there will be a index page showing up with all of the available url patterns.

Is there any way to customize this page by changing to a locally built and published play framework? I want to be able to do this in dev mode.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The all-available-routes-page is only shown in run/dev mode, not in production. It is there as a help for you as a developer to easily figure out why the url you accessed didn't lead anywhere.

You can override the not found page by adding a Global object with a onHandlerNotFound method to your liking. Read more in the play docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal